# How to create and access environment variables with GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

Here is a part of the workflow file:

```yaml
    env:
      resourceGroupName: 'rg-${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}'
```

I am trying to create an environment variable that concats a string and another environment variable but in the logs all I see from an echo from either way I can see is the following:

`echo "$resourceGroupName"` -> `rg-$***GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/***`

`echo "{{ env.resourceGroupName}}"` -> `*** env.resourceGroupName***`

Instead of what I'd have expected such as:

`rg-the-name-of-the-branch`

The docs do not seem particularly good in this regard. It also seems to be trying and failing to mask the variables as it's placing erroneous extra asterisks.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have `${{ github.ref }}` for it to work with the GitHub Actions vars. The linux envs are also exposed, so you can also use `$GITHUB_REF` directly without the brackets.

Alternatively, you can also use the format option to combine strings if you like that more:
`format("rb-{0}", ${{ github.ref }})`

Comment: You can create environment variables which I'm showing in the YAML. My question is how to access those.

Comment: You already got the env in your first echo (echo "$resourceGroupName" -> rg-$***GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/***), how else would the "rg-..." appear there? Your environment is just not correctly defined, which is why it gives the variable name back instead of resolving it. That is what I was trying to give you the correction for in my answer